# Cycling though popup windows in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, popupwindow

I created a main windows with 6 toggle buttons in Kivy.
I like to access a popup window with related settings via a long-press event on each of these toggle buttons.

The popup window is defined and has "next" and "previous" buttons to cycle from one settings page to the next one.

How can I avoid to create each of these popup definitions manually in Kivy?

Dummy .kv code:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
<MyPopup2@Popup>:
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: "Popup Window No. 2"
    Button:
        text: 'Close me, too!'
        on_release: root.dismiss()


MyPopup1@Popup:
    auto_dismiss: False
    size_hint: None,None
    size: 400,300
    title: "Popup Window No. 1"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text: 'Circuit Active:'
                Switch:
                    id: "switch1"
            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text: 'Default Watering Time: [min]'
                TextInput:    
                    text: '30'
            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text: 'Watering Group'
                TextInput:    
                    text: '3'
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Previous'
            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                on_release: root.dismiss()
            Button:
                text: 'Save + Exit'
            Button:
                text: 'Next'
                on_release: root.dismiss()
                on_release: Factory.MyPopup2().open()



BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: 5

    BoxLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 5
            ToggleButton:
                text: "Wasserkreis 1"
#               disabled: True
                on_release: Factory.MyPopup1().open()
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 5
            ToggleButton:
                text: "Wasserkreis 2"
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 5
            ToggleButton:
                text: "Wasserkreis 3"

    BoxLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 5
            ToggleButton:
                text: "Wasserkreis 4"
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 5
            ToggleButton:
                text: "Wasserkreis 5"
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 5
            ToggleButton:
                text: "Wasserkreis 6"

    BoxLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 5
            Label:
                text: 'Drei Zeilen\nmit\nStatusmeldungen'
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_x: 0.5
            padding: 5
            ToggleButton:
                text: "Automatik-\nBetrieb"
                on_press: app.testfunktion()
```

Comment: Are you trying to repeat the MyPopup1 and MyPopup2 for the remaining five buttons?

Comment: Yes, correct. I like to have 6 identical setting popup windows for the six garden watering valves, and I want to have "next" and "previous" buttons to go from one popup to the other without closing and going via the main screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same way, as you extended `Popup` you can also extend `MyPopup` you created. I implemented it for the first two Popups. It is straightforward to extend it. If you still have a question ask in the comments.

All the features `MyPopup` has are also in `MyPopup1` because it extends `MyPopup`. The title should be different and the previous and next are different for each Popup. Therefore you need to specify them.

```
<MyPopup1@MyPopup>:
        title: "Popup Window No. 1"
        call_previous:
        call_next: "Factory.MyPopup2().open()"
```

I am using eval in the MyPopup to "evaluate" these statements which are part of the root. See this extract from `MyPopup`:

```
on_release: eval(root.call_next)
```

Alternatively you could also give them just numbers and use maybe sth similar, but I'll leave that up to you.

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
<MyPopup1@MyPopup>:
    title: "Popup Window No. 1"
    call_previous:
    call_next: "Factory.MyPopup2().open()"

<MyPopup2@MyPopup>:
    title: "Popup Window No. 2"
    call_previous: "Factory.MyPopup1().open()"
    call_next: "Factory.MyPopup2().open()"

<MyPopup@Popup>:
    auto_dismiss: False
    size_hint: None,None
    size: 400,300
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text: 'Circuit Active:'
                Switch:
                    id: "switch1"
            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text: 'Default Watering Time: [min]'
                TextInput:    
                    text: '30'
            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text: 'Watering Group'
                TextInput:    
                    text: '3'
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Previous'
                on_release: root.dismiss()
                on_release: eval(root.call_previous)
            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                on_release: root.dismiss()
            Button:
                text: 'Save + Exit'
            Button:
                text: 'Next'
                on_release: root.dismiss()
                on_release: eval(root.call_next)



BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: 5

    BoxLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 5
            ToggleButton:
                text: "Wasserkreis 1"
#               disabled: True
                on_release: Factory.MyPopup1().open()
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 5
            ToggleButton:
                text: "Wasserkreis 2"
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 5
            ToggleButton:
                text: "Wasserkreis 3"

    BoxLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 5
            ToggleButton:
                text: "Wasserkreis 4"
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 5
            ToggleButton:
                text: "Wasserkreis 5"
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 5
            ToggleButton:
                text: "Wasserkreis 6"

    BoxLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 5
            Label:
                text: 'Drei Zeilen\nmit\nStatusmeldungen'
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_x: 0.5
            padding: 5
            ToggleButton:
                text: "Automatik-\nBetrieb"
                on_press: app.testfunktion()
```

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping that there is a more generic approach which gives "context" to the  popup and avoids the code duplication.

Comment: what do you mean by context? I think 4 lines per Popup is really good. I don't see any code repetition. you can define more properties as I did, to make a widget tailored to your needs.

Comment: Sorry, I think I get it now. The full content is inherited into the different popup.

Comment: I updated my answer with an explanation, hope it helps.

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so consider accepting or if it just helped you, you may consider upvoting it.